# What is the equivalend MathNet.Numerics of Excel TINV function?

Tags: c#, excel, mathnet-numerics

Excel's `TINV` function is described as

*Returns the two-tailed inverse of the Student's t-distribution.*

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TINV-function-a7c85b9d-90f5-41fe-9ca5-1cd2f3e1ed7c

**What is the equivalent `C#` function in MathNet.Numerics?**

https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/StudentT.htm

I guessed that it is the method `InvCDF` of `StudentT`

```
double InvCDF(double location, double scale, double freedom, double p)
```

But what is confusing me is that TINV only takes two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `MathNet.Numerics` had the foresight to add typical `Excel` functions in the `ExcelFunctions` `namespace`. At this time, the `MathNet.Numerics` version of `TINV` is documented here:

https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/ExcelFunctions.htm